# No table is created after I deleted table (CodeFirst)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a table in a database using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and then I used the `AddOrUpdate`method; but my data did not get overwritten, but added again instead.
I deleted the whole table and compiled my program again but an error occurred.

```
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
  HResult=0x8013193C
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  Ślad stosu:
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery\`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func\`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery\`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   w System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func\`1 operation)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery\`1.GetResults(Nullable\`1 forMergeOption)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery\`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   w System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator\`1.MoveNext()
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable\`1 sequence)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable\`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   w System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   w System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet\`1 set, IEnumerable\`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet\`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet\`1 set, TEntity[] entities)
   w StoreProject.DAL.StoreInitializer.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<SeedStoreData>b__0(Product a) w C:\Users\krysw\source\repos\StoreWebsite\StoreProject\DAL\StoreInitializer.cs:wiersz 23
   w System.Collections.Generic.List\`1.ForEach(Action\`1 action)
   w StoreProject.DAL.StoreInitializer.SeedStoreData(StoreContext context) w C:\Users\krysw\source\repos\StoreWebsite\StoreProject\DAL\StoreInitializer.cs:wiersz 23
   w StoreProject.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(StoreContext context) w C:\Users\krysw\source\repos\StoreWebsite\StoreProject\Migrations\Configuration.cs:wiersz 20
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration\`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable\`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Update>b__d()
   w System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)

> Wewnętrzny wyjątek 1:
SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Products'.
```

Comment: did you look at the last line of the exception `Wewnętrzny wyjątek 1: SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Products'` to see if you know the problem with that

Comment: So why this table is not creating?

Comment: Ok I did a query which added this table again and it works.